# command window appears and disappears after cgi script is run

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to python cgi script and I am trying to learn how to setup a server and run cgi script. I was following a simple example and got this weird situation. Here is the code for setup the server on windows 8

```
import os, sys
from http.server import HTTPServer, CGIHTTPRequestHandler

webdir='c:/python34/webdir'
port=2000

os.chdir(webdir)
srvraddr=("",port)
srvrobj=HTTPServer(srvraddr, CGIHTTPRequestHandler)
srvrobj.serve_forever()
```

and the html file is

```
<html>
<title>Interactive Page</title>
<body>
<form method=POST action="cgi-bin/cgi101.py">
<P><B>Enter your name:</B>
<P><input type=text name=user>
<P><input type=submit>
</form>
</body></html>
```

The python cgi code to handle this is:

```
import cgi
form=cgi.FieldStorage()
print('Content-type:text/html\n')
print('<title>Reply Page</title>')
if not 'user' in form:
    print('<h1>who are you?</h1>')
else:
    print('<h1>hello <i>%s</i>!</h1>'%cgi.escape(form['user'].value))
```

I got the server to run and also the python cgi code runs perfectly. But each time the command prompt window appears and disappears before the browser would display the result of the cgi code. I don't think that was normal but don't know what was the problem to cause the command prompt window to appear and disappear. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The python.exe interpreter is doing this. Without the command window any attempts to use `print()` and such in a normal script would result in an exception due to stdout not being connected to anything. The fix is to have your script use the pythonw.exe interpreter instead by changing its extension to .pyw instead of .py.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I changed the extension of my script to .pyw and also the name in the html file. But I still see that window come and go.